# upload image and store with different name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

**There're three process should be here;**

- move the image to the folder in public path : `/charts/`
- store the different name which should not same (auto number for image)
- store the name of image into `charts` at columns name as `file`

Table Stucture: `charts`

[image]

```html
<div class="form-group col-lg-10">
                {!! Form::label('file', 'Chart upload:') !!}
                {!! Form::file('file', null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>
```

**I have done much here :**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

        $input = $request->all();

    if($file = $request->file('file'))
    {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('charts', $name);
        charts::create(['file'=>$name]);
    }
}
```

**MODEL**:

```
    class charts extends Model
{
    //
    protected $uploads = '/upload/';
    protected $fillable = ['file', 'trade_id'];
    public function getFileAttribute($photo)
    {
        return $this->uploads . $photo;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What you want to achieve?

Comment: not `storing data` and nothing is happening. I might missing something in my `function` @claudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{ Form::file('file', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}` - second argument must be an array ( By Default Function Prototype)

Please check your permissions for writing in `charts` folder
In Linux console, for example, use: `sudo chmod 755 charts`

Also, you might change folder's owner to `www-data` so web server process can access that folder. In Linux console: `sudo chown www-data charts`

To rename file you might use php `rename( string $oldname, string $newname)` function after your `$file->move('charts', $name);`

```
$newname = 'cool-name' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();  
rename($name , $newname);
```

After renaming you can save info into database
To save data in database:

```
DB::table('charts')->insert(
    [  'trade_id' => 12345,    // 12345 Trader id example
           'file' => $newname, // new filename
     'created_at' => time(),   // current timestamp
     'updated_ad' => time()]   // current timestamp
);
```

Comment: You follow `second argument in array` for forum and `777` permission for folder, but i dont understand how to use`your code` because of not families in development.

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati
`public function store(Request $request)
{

        $input = $request->all();

    if($file = $request->file('file'))
    {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('charts', $name);

        $newname = 'cool-name' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();  

        rename($name , $newname); 
        DB::table('charts')->insert(
        [  'trade_id' => 12345,           
           'file' => $newname,             
           'created_at' => time(),        
           'updated_ad' => time()]       
       );

    }
}`

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm  here is explanatory article about file permissions. Also i suggest you to check youtube.com, video works better if you are not really familiar with this topic.
Sometimes script cannot save the file into folder because of permisiions. Simple way to check it: 
1. Rigth click on the forder
2. Click properties
3. Click on tab permissions, here you will see Group, Owner and Others type of users. Each type have its own permission 'access files', 'create and delete files' changing this you will change users permissions.

Comment: Now my code is worked but problem with name... `Untitled.extentions` storing like this.

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati
That's might be because any file extension is after the dot.   Try to add dot "." between filename and extension.  `$newname = 'cool-name' . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();`. Also to have unique filename you might change string `'cool-name'` to something like `time() . base_convert(rand(1,999999), 10,16)`

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati 

public function store(Request $request) {  
   $input = $request->all();   
   if($file = $request->file('file')) {   
$name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName(); $file->move('charts', $name); $newname = time() . base_convert(rand(1,999999), 10,16) . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); rename($name , $newname); DB::table('charts')->insert( [ 'trade_id' => 12345, 'file' => $newname, 'created_at' => time(), 'updated_ad' => time()] ); } }

Comment: If you type here, it will hard to understand for me. actually i dont have deep knowledge for developing. I am trying to learn. Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50881065/image-dose-not-move-at-folder-path/50881559#50881559 you can answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use for this,

```
if($file = $request->file('file'))
    {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $request->file('file')->storeAs(
                   'charts', newName
                             );
        charts::create(['file'=>$name]);
    }
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I paste this code to my `controller` but, result nothing. not storing data into table &  not storing image. @webdevtr