# Image dose not move at folder path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I already given `777 permission` to my `images` folder. `Charts Table` is also saving all record of image. I am going to attach table:`charts` structure here.

[image]

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
        $input = $request->all();
        $tradeID= Auth::user()->trade()->create($input);

    if($file = $request->file('file'))
    {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('images', $name);
        $photo = Chart::create(['file'=>$name]);
        $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id;
    }
        $tradeID->chart()->create($input);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change destination path from relative to absolute

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();
    $tradeID= Auth::user()->trade()->create($input);

    if($file = $request->file('file'))
    {
        $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move( public_path() . '/images/', $name);  // absolute destination path
        $photo = Chart::create(['file'=>$name]);
        $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id;
    }
        $tradeID->chart()->create($input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to move uploaded file or existing file ?

To move file you need to do:

```
File::move($oldPath, $newPath);
```

the old path and new path should include full path with filename (and extension)

To store an uploaded file you need to do:

```
Storage::disk('diskname')->put($newPath, File::get($file));
```

the new path is full path with filename (and extension).

- disk is optional , you can store file directly with `Storage::put()`..
- Disks are located in `config/filesystems.php`

The `File::get($file)` , `$file` is your input from post request `$file = $request->file('file')` , basically it gets contents of uploaded file.

UPD#1

Okay , you can do this:

```
$request->file('file')->store(public_path('images'));
```

Or with Storage class:

```
    // get uploaded file
    $file = $request->file('file');
    // returns the original file name.
    $original = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    // get filename with extension like demo.php
    $filename = pathinfo($original)['basename'];
    // get public path to images folder
    $path = public_path('images');
    // concat public path with filename
    $filePath = $path.'/'.$filename;
    // store uploaded file to path
    $store = Storage::put($filePath, File::get($file));
```

Comment: I have folder name as `images` in public path. I want to move uploaded image to this folder.

Comment: @KinnariPrajapati see UPD#1

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if($file = $request->file('file'))
{
    $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $file->storeAs('images', $name,'public');
    $photo = Chart::create(['file'=>$name]);
    $input['photo_id'] = $photo->id;
}
```

you can retreive the file with `/storage/public/file_name` or `/file_name` depending on where you told laravel to store the public files

Comment: this code is also not working to store file in `images` folder

Comment: Where exactly the problem?, In the path or the file not being added?

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually storing the file, you are actually moving a non-existent file.

**What you might consider**
You, most probably want to access uploaded file from public path. If so, you should store this file to particular folder in your storage directory and create a symlink to that directory in your public path.
Here's an example:

```
Storage::disks('public')->put($filename, $uploadedFile); // filename = 'images/imageFile.jpg'
```

This creates a file in your `storage/app/public/images` directory.

Then, you can create a symlink, laravel provide a simple command to do so.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This creates a symlink to your public disk.

Then, you can access the image at `http://your-site-server/storage/images/imageFile.jpg`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am unable to understand because, I try to upload image but, in the `images` folder nothing to result.

Comment: See you are using a move function... When a file is uoloaded it is in some temporary directory, you are not actually copying that uploaded file. Did you try what I explained?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $name = time().'.'. $file->getClientOriginalName(); //depends on ur requirement
        $file->move(public_path('images'), $name);
```