# File Upload in Laravel with Validation giving issues and failing with white screen and no errors

Tags: php, laravel, file, controller, upload

I have been trying to follow some guides on file uploads with Laravel PHP but am hitting a road block.  Currently my below controller compiles with no errors but brings me to a white page and my file uploads do not appear to making it to my storage location.  I have gotten image uploads to work but I want this to be an image, audio, or video upload capability which I have not been able to get it to work.  I am struggling on how to debug this code to see where it could be going wrong.  Is it because of my return statement inside of the if statement?  Amateur here and will appreciate any help here.

Thanks

See below for my referenced resources and controller.

https://appdividend.com/2018/08/15/laravel-file-upload-example

[Image dose not move at folder path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50881065/image-dose-not-move-at-folder-path)

https://www.webslesson.info/2018/02/image-file-upload-in-laravel-with-validation.html

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class UploadfileController extends Controller
{
  function index()
  {
   return view('upload');
  }

function upload(Request $request)
{

 if( $request->hasFile('file') ) {

    $file = $request->file('file');
    $imagemimes = ['image/jpeg,png']; //Add more mimes that you want to support
    $videomimes = ['video/mp4,mpeg,ogg,mp4,webm,3gp,mov,flv,avi,wmv,ts']; //Add more mimes that you want to support
    $audiomimes = ['audio/mpeg,mpga,mp3,wav,aac']; //Add more mimes that you want to support

    //Validate images
    if(in_array($file->getMimeType() ,$imagemimes)) {
            $filevalidate = 'required|mimes:jpeg,png|max:2048';
    }
    //Validate video
    if (in_array($file->getMimeType() ,$videomimes)) {
            $filevalidate = 'required|file|mimes:mpeg,ogg,mp4,webm,3gp,mov,flv,avi,wmv,ts|max:4000040';
    }
    //validate audio
    if (in_array($file->getMimeType() ,$audiomimes)) {
            $filevalidate = 'required|file|mimes:audio/mpeg,mpga,mp3,wav,aac|max:90048';
    }

 $original = $file->getClientOriginalName();
 // get filename with extension like demo.php
 $filename = pathinfo($original)['basename'];
 // get public path to images folder
 $path = public_path('files');
 // concat public path with filename
 $filePath = $path.'/'.$filename;
 // store uploaded file to path
 $store = Storage::put($filePath, File::get($file));

 return back()->with('success', 'Media Uploaded Successfully')->with('path', $store);

}
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the laravel.log file?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing in the laravel.log either

Answer (score 0):

The field you are sending from your front-end is called 'file', right? Just checking.

My first thought is that your program might not be making it into your if statement, which would explain the white screen.
First, I'd recommend you `return var_dump($request->hasFile('file'));`
See if that returns true or false.

Then, maybe try to `return [$request->file('file')];` and see what it says... And then we'll go from there. I'm no expert but I think I can help a bit =)

Comment: you were right, return var_dump($request->hasFile('file')); returns False and return [$request->file('file')]; returns null

Comment: But "file" is the name of your input field? What if you `return $request->all()`;

Comment: Hello, @GregGelman, were you able to figure out what the problem was?

Comment: Not yet, no.  I will try the request all later today.  There is alot of guidance on how to do images but not other file types.  I just want to be able to upload any file and regardless of size.

Comment: Well not regardless of size, within limition of maybe up to 5gb at a time.